# Assign font family to text using HTML string in to TextView or load into WebView

Tags: android, html, textview, android-webview, font-family

My need is to set HTML string into TextView but the problem is the `<p style=\"text-align:center\"><span style=\"font-family:montserrat\"><span style=\"color:#660099\"><strong>Hello World</strong></span></span></p>\r\n`

That `font-family:montserrat` is not applied to Text.

**Note:** I tried to load this HTML string using **WebView** but there is also same problem is raising.

Please suggest a workaround.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add your font file to your android project, in your case:
montserrat.tff

Define like this in your html string:

```
@font-face { font-family: montserrat; src: url('fonts/montserrat.ttf'); }
```

Then try like this:

```
yourWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",htmlString,"text/html","utf-8",null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is working but I want to try that, can we load font-family without .ttf OR .otf font files in Android App?